# Objective-C (iOS), Image resizing using CIFilter produces invalid output (UIImage)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, image-resizing, cifilter

I'm trying to resize JPEG image in Objective-C (iOS). Input is a JPG file and output should be `UIImage`.

I have this code:

```
// Load image from a file
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jpgFile];
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
CIImage *ciImage = inputImage.CIImage;

// Set Lanczos filter
CIFilter *scaleFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform"];
[scaleFilter setValue:ciImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[scaleFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5] forKey:@"inputScale"];
[scaleFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputAspectRatio"];

// Get an output
CIImage *finalImage = [scaleFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
UIImage *outputImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:finalImage];
```

But the output image is invalid (`outputImage.size.height is 0`), and it causes following errors in an other processing:

> CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the
>   backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable. ImageIO: JPEG Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)

---

**Update:**

I don't know, what is wrong with the code above (except the initialization mentioned by Sulthan below - thank him for that). I used following code at the end (this code works OK):

```
CIImage *input_ciimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
CIImage *output_ciimage =
    [[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform" keysAndValues:
    kCIInputImageKey, input_ciimage,
    kCIInputScaleKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
    nil] outputImage];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef output_cgimage = [context createCGImage:output_ciimage fromRect:[output_ciimage extent]];
UIImage *output_uiimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:output_cgimage];
CGImageRelease(output_cgimage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
CIImage *ciImage = inputImage.CIImage
```

If the image is not initialized from a `CIImage` then it's own `CIImage` is `nil`. 
A safer approach is:

```
CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
```

Also, make sure the image has been loaded successfully from your data.

Comment: It changed a little. it processes an image (error is still there - without the JPEG part), but image is black or filled with color noise, outputImage.size.height a width variables are nonsence numbers (large or negative values).  Anything else that can be wrong with that?

Comment: @Jolinar My guess is that your original image is not loaded properly. Did you check the size of `inputImage`?

Comment: Yes, original image has real WxH and is processed ok (there are some color corrections, and JPEG export), if the resize is not performed.